# Why isn't my Style.css updating on Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to make the font on my website a little bit larger. I thought this would be a super simple fix. Just jump into the Style.css file and up the body font size. But I found that when I did this, it didn't update on the front end despite the file being updated for sure.

I realized when I dug into the source code, there seems to be a line of code added to the end of the link to the stylesheet that appears to be preventing the new update from being reflected - "?ver=4.8". Check it out below:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='font-awesome-css'  href='http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/the-social-links/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=4.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='the-social-links-style-css'  href='http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/the-social-links/assets/css/style.css?ver=4.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='http://www.example.com/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'  href='http://www.example.com/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=4.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='sb_instagram_styles-css'  href='http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/instagram-feed/css/sb-instagram.min.css?ver=1.4.9' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='sb_instagram_icons-css'  href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=4.6.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='blaskan-fonts-css'  href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif%3A400%2C700%7CSource+Sans+Pro%3A300%2C400%2C600%2C700%2C900%7CWork+Sans%7CPacifico&#038;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext&#038;ver=4.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css'  href='http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/blaskan/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=4.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='fontawesome-css'  href='http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/blaskan/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=4.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='blaskan-style-css'  href='http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/blaskan/style.css?ver=4.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='tablepress-default-css'  href='http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/tablepress/css/default.min.css?ver=1.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

It's the second to last stylesheet that I want to update. So, I thought that I could just jump into the header.php file to remove that weird code at the end that appears to be overriding the update, but when I opened the file, all I see there is:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

No stylesheet links in sight.

Can anybody tell me where I can edit the stylesheet code to remove that "ver=4.8" code from the end?

The them I'm using is https://wordpress.org/themes/blaskan/, if that helps.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to make a child theme and put your css in there.

Comment: ctrl+f5 for hard refresh. Most likely the CSS file is cached by your browser. It may also be cached by your server.

Comment: Also, the 4.9 is the version number and it's there to be a [cache buster](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would normally not modify the themes css directly. The correct way to do this, is to create a child theme and modify the CSS-Files of your child theme. [Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) is an instruction on how you can create a child theme.

Wordpress even suggests using a child theme:

> There are a few reasons why you would want to use a child theme:
>
> If you modify a theme directly and it is updated, then your
>   modifications may be lost. By using a child theme you will ensure that
>   your modifications are preserved. Using a child theme can speed up
>   development time. Using a child theme is a great way to learn about
>   WordPress theme development.

Comment: Aaaaaah. Well that explains it. Thank you. I'll look into making a child theme!